# Select rows from multiple tables based on date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

So I am trying to select multiple rows from multiple tables based on date. So there are comments, votes and reviews. Normally I would grab 10 votes based on date, then 10 comments based on date, then 10 reviews. However I want to do this all at once so they are sorted.

How can I say grab 30 (votes + reviews + comments) (all separate tables) so that I get a unique mix of comments / votes/ reviews and always the most recent 30. I assume its something like:

`SELECT * from votes, comments, reviews ORDERBY 'created_at', 'DESC'`

Comment: This will create one large cross join. Need you to clarify...are you looking for data across all three tables to come back, or are you looking for top 10 lines from each table?  In first case, we need keys to join your tables correctly...if second choice, then it's unioning three statements together

Comment: are you looking for a raw sql answer or the laravel way, since you put laravel in the tags?

Comment: Are the structures of the tables anywhere close?

Comment: the table structures are similar but not exact, I am looking for mysql or laravel, and to answer the first comment, I am looking for 30 rows, they can be comments, votes or reviews as long as I get 30, (the relevant info is the same on all 3 tables)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `UNION`

```
SELECT created_at, votecomment AS comment FROM votes
UNION ALL
SELECT created_at, comment AS comment FROM comments
UNION ALL
SELECT created_at, reviewcomment AS comment FROM reviews
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

Comment: +1. This can also be done without an inline view; just use that inline view query, and specify the sort expression by position in the resultset, rather than by name: `ORDER BY 1 DESC`.

Answer (score 0):

What you've got is a cartesian query. If each of those tables has (say) 100 records, then you'll end up with 100x100x100 = 1,000,000 returned records.

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 'votes' AS source_table, * FROM votes ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'comments', * FROM comments ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'reviews', * FROM reviews ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10
) AS required_alias
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Each of the subqueries fetches the 10 most recent records from your three 3 tables. The outer query takes those 30 rows, and re-sorts them so those 30 rows are again in date/time ordering.

The fixed string votes/comments/reviews stuff is simply so you can identify WHICH table the individual records came from afterwards.

And of course, this will only work if the three tables have identical structures. If they have differing numbers of fields and/or the types differ, the the union will fail.

Comment: this will only work if all the tables are structured equal, otherwise the union will fail

Comment: echoing chresse: the number of columns and datatype of each column (by position) would need to match in order for the UNION ALL to operate. If the query works now, adding or removing a column from any one of the tables will cause the query to be broken. I don't think MySQL allows an ORDER BY on a query within a UNION ALL; MySQL allows only one ORDER BY, after the last SELECT, and it applies to the entire set.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to return the specified resultset:

```
SELECT v.created_at, v.fee  AS fee, v.fi  AS fi FROM votes v
 UNION ALL
SELECT c.created_at, c.fo   AS fee, ''    AS fi FROM comments c
 UNION ALL
SELECT r.created_at, r.fum  AS fee, r.foo AS fi FROM reviews r
 ORDER BY 1 DESC
 LIMIT 30
```

Note that the number of columns returned by each query must match, and the datatypes returned by each query must match.

(To make the columns "line up", we can include extra expressions in the SELECT list, like shown in the query from the `comments` table above. An expression can also do datatype conversions as well. The aliases assigned to the columns in the second and third queries don't matter, the names of the columns in the resultset are derived from the first select. They are included in the example above just as a demonstration of getting columns "line up"... the aliases aren't important.)